# cannot import name 'Definitions' from 'dagster'

Tags: python, dagster

I'm trying out this example project: https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/tree/master/examples/project_fully_featured

I added a workspace.yaml file with the lines:

```
load_from:
  - python_module: project_fully_featured
```

Which was necessary to run the `dagit` command without further options, as described in the github repo readme.

However, when running the `dagit` command, I get the following error:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/workspace/context.py:538: UserWarning: Error loading repository location project_fully_featured:dagster._core.errors.DagsterImportError: Encountered ImportError: `cannot import name 'Definitions' from 'dagster' (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/__init__.py)` while importing module project_fully_featured. Local modules were resolved using the working directory `/Users/<name>/Documents/dev/tutorials/tutorial_dagster_project_fully_featured/my-dagster-project`. If another working directory should be used, please explicitly specify the appropriate path using the `-d` or `--working-directory` for CLI based targets or the `working_directory` configuration option for workspace targets. 

Stack Trace:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/server.py", line 230, in __init__
    self._loaded_repositories: Optional[LoadedRepositories] = LoadedRepositories(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/server.py", line 104, in __init__
    loadable_targets = get_loadable_targets(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_grpc/utils.py", line 43, in get_loadable_targets
    else loadable_targets_from_python_module(module_name, working_directory)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/workspace/autodiscovery.py", line 36, in loadable_targets_from_python_module
    module = load_python_module(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/code_pointer.py", line 141, in load_python_module
    raise DagsterImportError(

The above exception was caused by the following exception:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Definitions' from 'dagster' (/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/__init__.py)

Stack Trace:
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dagster/_core/code_pointer.py", line 136, in load_python_module
    return importlib.import_module(module_name)
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.16/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/<name>/Documents/dev/tutorials/tutorial_dagster_project_fully_featured/my-dagster-project/project_fully_featured/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from dagster import Definitions

  warnings.warn(
2023-03-20 12:36:20 +0100 - dagit - INFO - Serving dagit on http://127.0.0.1:3000 in process 63845
```

When I run python3 in my terminal window and run 'from dagster import Definitions', all seems to work fine, no error thrown there.